# Subordinate conjunctions - Semicolon before acceptable?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, subordinate-clauses

What would be correct?

- The word "sacred" means "regarded with great respect and reverence", and the word is most commonly used in religious meaning; however,...

Or

- The word "sacred" means "regarded with great respect and reverence", and the word is most commonly used in religious meaning. However,...

Or

- The word "sacred" means "regarded with great respect and reverence", and the word is most commonly used in religious meaning, however,...

Comment: Both semicolon and full stop are fine. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

The first and second ways are correct. "however" is preceded by a semicolon or a full stop (period).
http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/semicolons.asp
"Bring any two items; however, sleeping bags and tents are in short supply."
http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/can-you-start-sentence-however
"However, I loved all seven of Anne's Oscar dresses (plus the tuxedo)."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. StackExchange is about building a library of *definitive* answers to questions, and as such, answers should provide a full explanation, including suitable references and examples you may find. Otherwise, it is simply another anonymous opinion from the Internet. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for guidance.

Comment: You say " including suitable references", but a reference I provided on another question was deleted, so I'm confused.